# Changing Ranking Model for Business Essentials licensed SharePoint Online tenancy

Tags: sharepoint-online, central-administration, ranking

All of the documentation I've found refers to changing the Ranking model using the Central Administration module, or by using the SharePoint Online Management Shell.  Due to my company's Business Essential license

- Central Administration feature is not available See [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_Featurecomparison)
- The cmdlets used in the SP Mgmt Shell to change the ranking model are not available to a SharePoint Online tenancy.  See [link](https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-powershell-cmdlets-listed-onprem-vs-online/#365)

So is it impossible to change the Ranking Model for a SharePoint Online tenancy that is owned by an organization that only has a Business Essential license?

Comment: Someone did point me to an article regarding the managing of result sources, however the article doesn't specifically discuss the rank model.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-result-sources-fd8d6ac6-c5d0-454d-80a9-51580902b25d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rank Model being used is determined by the default Results Source.  A Result Source is the name given to the configuration entity that determines the limitations imposed on search results.  One of the configurations for a Result Source is to determine the method of its sort.  If a Results Source is configured to sort by the relevance rankings, the SharePoint Administrator can determine which Rank Model is being used to calculate the Rank score of the Search Results.

Manage Result Sources

1. Log into Office 365
2. Click on the Sites application
3. Click on the “Team Site” Site Collection
4. Click on the Site Contents link, located on the left side menu
5. Locate and click on a Sub-Site.
6. Click on the Settings menu   icon located in the upper right corner.
7. Click on Site Settings.
8. On the Search header on the Site Settings page, click Result Sources.
9. Opens the Manage Result Sources.
10. Click New Result Source
11. Add Result Source page
    a.  Name – As desired
    b.  Description – As desired
    c.  Protocol – Local SharePoint
    d.  Type – SharePoint Search Results
    e.  Credential Information – Default Authentication
12. Click on the Launch Query Builder button
13. Navigate to the Sorting tab
14. Set Sort by to Rank
15. Set Ranking Model as desired
16. Make additional adjustments as desired.  Click Ok to save Build Your Query options.
17. Click Save to save the Result Source
18. Click to the right of the Result Source name, a menu will appear.
19. Click Set as Default

So this is a round about way to use a different Rank Model, but it doesn't apparently change the Default Rank Model set for a Site.